# How to update my access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

Hi i have a code on how to update data in my access database in my vb.net  but when ever i try it i get errors, this is my code. and my app interface as well.

```
Private Sub Update_Record_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Update_Record.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.EmployeeRegistrationBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.EmployeeRegistrationTableAdapter.Update(Me.PayrollManagerDBDataSet)
    TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.PayrollManagerDBDataSet)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. What's the error message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: An UPDATE or DELETE query cannot contain a multi-valued field.                                this is the error

Answer (score 1):

That error message suggests that one of your table columns is type `Attachment`.  Unfortunately, ADO.NET does not provide support for `Attachment` columns.  You can retrieve data with a bit of jiggery-pokery but saving data is, as far as I've been able to determine, impossible.  If you search the web you will find some solutions for saving data to `Attachment` columns that use DAO.

Comment: so please what do u suggest i do

Comment: It's like people just put their brain in neutral sometimes.  I said that ADO.NET doesn't support `Attachment` columns.  Obviously you either can't use `Attachment` columns or you can't use ADO.NET, to work with that column at least.  If you want to keep using `Attachment` columns then you will have to, as I have already said, use DAO.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: yes but what do you suggest they do?

Comment: @onedaywhen, I can't reasonably answer that question with the information I have. The simplest option is to not use `Attachment` columns but I don't know whether that's possible or not. I don't know whether they have any experience with DAO or inclination to learn. I've provided an explanation of what I believe the issue is and options for how to work around it. The OP has to think for themselves from there.

Answer (score 0):

The OLE DB provider for the Access Database Engine is 'owned' by the SQL Server team since circa Access 2000 when they were tasked in making Access work with SQL Server and to make Jet (.mdb) work like SQL Server. Because they failed in - or perhaps the market/community *rejected* - their efforts, the Access team took a 'private copy' of the code base and went their own way with the .accdb version of the Access Database Engine. So when they added new data types to the .accdb they were free to add they to ACEDAO but they could not change the OLE DB provider because they don't own it (and probably couldn't justify doing so anyhow because the Access community rejected ADO classic years ago). This is why you can't use OLE DB to programmatically modify `Attachment` data and the only realistic option is to use ACEDAO.